# Hide element in inherit qweb odoo 9

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

Is it possible with xpath exp in inherit qweb hide below line?

```
<t t-set="doc" t-value="doc.with_context({'lang':doc.partner_id.lang})" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use replace and you have to identify the correct node. So identify the node and replace it.

```
<xpath expr="//t[last()]" position="replace">
    <!-- <t t-set="doc" t-value="doc.with_context({'lang':doc.partner_id.lang})" /> -->
</xpath>
```

I usually like to replace it with a commented out version of itself. Also the above will only work if the `t` tag is the last in the document.

You may have to capture a parent node and inject all of the existing xml with your desired `t` element commented out or removed. You may also be able to use these expressions or some variation of them.

```
expr="//div[@name='div_name']/t"
expr="//div[@name='div_name']/t[first()]"
```

Comment: Hello, In my solution http://imgur.com/hEvwJOr I don't have div for your second example. How use in this situation?

Comment: If it is not a div you can replace that with whatever node type the element is. You should search the source for other examples.